# How to animate the layer of a lottie animation?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, lottie

I have an `UIView` with several other `UIViews` as `subviews`. Each one of these `subviews` can be clicked, and when they are they will animate their `layer` and "pop" out which makes it look like it's selected. But in each `subview` I also have a Lottie animation.

When I select one of these `subview UIViews` the Lottie Animation is not tagging along, it simply pops into the right position after my select animation is finished. It's almost as if the `layer` of my Lottie animation is not in my `UIViews layer hierarchy`. But if I don't play my lottie animation and simply pause it, it works fine. This is how I create my lottie animation object, from a json created in After Effects:

```
 - (CALayer *)fetchAnimationForIcon:(NSString *)iconName {
    LOTAnimationView *a = [LOTAnimationView animationNamed:iconName];
    [a play];

    return a.layer;
}
```

I then add this `layer` as a `sublayer` to the `UIView` calling this method. I then proceed to animate the select animation on this `UIView`, which causes `a.layer` to pop or blink into correct position. It simply isn't animating while running. But if I don't play the animation it all works fine.

Comment: did you find any solution of this ? 
I trying the same to add lottie in video and having same issue.

Comment: If I remember correctly there was an issue with the way our app handles layers and the way lottie does it. I was adding the animation to the layer which didn't really work that well when using lottie for some reason. I don't remember how we fixed it though, sorry :(

Comment: any gist you can remember?

Comment: @SkBorhanUddin sorry no, I wasn't the one who fixed it and it was so long ago. I don't even work on that project anymore, sorry :/